# Submit message java script

Tags: javascript, php

What I want to do is if the user send a message for the first time it will submit intantly but if the user send a message for the 2nd time, the user needs to wait for 5 seconds to be able to submit the request. Im sorry if I didnt post any code I just start coding but can you provide your answer in this example?`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="try"></p>
 <textarea id="txtbx" name="txtbx" rows="4" cols="50">
 </textarea>
<div class="btn">
        <span class="Btn" id="Sendbtn">
          <button type="submit">Send</button>
        </span>
      </div>
      
<?php
echo "";
?> 
</body>
</html>
```

`

Comment: it's hard to help with no code - simple method, disable "send" for 5 seconds after sending

Comment: Is there anything you've tried? Stuck on any particular bit? Done any research? Got any code for us? See also [ask] and the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

```js
 let firstSend=false;
    // when first time he/she first clicked on send set its value to true
    if(firstSend==true){
        setTimeout("wait for 5 seconds",1000)
        // continue your rest of the code
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dah77.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlnSW.png)
I hope it helps